# Solving $\frac{1}{(x-1)} - \frac{1}{(x-2)} = \frac{1}{(x-3)} - \frac{1}{(x-4)}$. Why is my solution wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm following all hitherto me known rules for solving equations, but the result is wrong. Please explain why my approach is not correct.

We want to solve:

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)} - \frac{1}{(x-2)} = \frac{1}{(x-3)} - \frac{1}{(x-4)}\tag1$$

Moving the things in RHS to LHS:

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)} - \frac{1}{(x-2)} - \frac{1}{(x-3)} + \frac{1}{(x-4)} = 0\tag2$$

Writing everything above a common denominator:

$$\frac{1}{(x-4)(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)}\bigg[(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) - (x-1)(x-3)(x-4) - (x-2)(x-1)(x-4) + (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\bigg] = 0\tag3$$

Multiplying both sides with the denominator to cancel the denominator:

$$(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) - (x-1)(x-3)(x-4) - (x-2)(x-1)(x-4) + (x-1)(x-2)(x-3) = 0\tag4$$

Multiplying the first two factors in every term:

$$(x^2-3x-2x+6)(x-4) - (x^2-3x-x+3)(x-4) - (x^2-x-2x+2)(x-4) + (x^2-2x-x+2)(x-3) = 0\tag5$$

Simplifying the first factors in every term:

$$(x^2-5x+6)(x-4) - (x^2-4x+3)(x-4) - (x^2-3x+2)(x-4) + (x^2-3x+2)(x-3) = 0\tag6$$

Multiplying factors again:

$$(x^3-4x^2-5x^2+20x+6x-24) - (x^3-4x^2-4x^2+16x+3x-12) - (x^3-4x^2-3x^2-12x+2x-8) + (x^3-3x^2-3x^2+9x+2x-6) = 0\tag7$$

Removing the parenthesis yields:

$$x^3-4x^2-5x^2+20x+6x-24 - x^3+4x^2+4x^2-16x-3x+12 - x^3+4x^2+3x^2+12x-2x+8 + x^3-3x^2-3x^2+9x+2x-6 = 0\tag8$$

Which results in:

$$28x - 10 = 0 \Rightarrow 28x = 10 \Rightarrow x = \frac{5}{14}\tag9$$
which is not correct. The correct answer is $x = \frac{5}{2}$.

Comment: I haven't looked, but probably a simple arithmetic error (sign error most likely). But you made it harder by getting everything on one side. Instead, start by simplifying each side separately. Then cross-multiply.

Comment: +1, nice question, not because of the mistake you did but because if you find the equation symmetric about 5/2 and substitute x-(5/2)=y, see where it leads

Comment: Hint.  For you sanity simplify before removing the parenthises in the second to last step.  You just so many like terms you are bound to make an error somewhere.

Comment: In the second to last line you have a -12x when it should be a +12x.

Comment: A big tip : simplify LHS and RHS separately, you will greatly reduce the number of steps and number of parenthesis

Comment: So you end up with 24x when it should be 4x.

Comment: You can easily check that you just made a mistake in some calculation: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-2%29%28x-3%29%28x-4%29+-+%28x-1%29%28x-3%29%28x-4%29+-+%28x-2%29%28x-1%29%28x-4%29+%2B+%28x-1%29%28x-2%29%28x-3%29&x=0&y=0 Now do the same for the following lines to see at which point you get a different result.

Comment: With the help of a CAS, $(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) - (x-1)(x-3)(x-4) - (x-2)(x-1)(x-4) + (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=4x-10$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But as I suggested in my comment, the better approach is to first simplify each side separately . . .
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x-2} = \frac{1}{x-3} - \frac{1}{x-4}\\[4pt]
\implies\;
&\frac{(x-2)-(x-1)}{(x-1)(x-2)}=\frac{(x-4)-(x-3)}{(x-3)(x-4)}\\[4pt]
\implies\;
&\frac{-1}{(x-1)(x-2)}=\frac{-1}{(x-3)(x-4)}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(-1)(x-3)(x-4)=(-1)(x-1)(x-2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(x-3)(x-4)=(x-1)(x-2)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x^2-7x+12=x^2-3x+2\\[4pt]
\implies\;&4x=10\\[4pt]
\implies\;&x=\frac{5}{2}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Also note, as warned about in Mark Bennet's reply, we have to worry about canceling algebraic factors that might actually be equal to zero. In the steps above, the factors
$$(x-1),\;(x-2),\;(x-3),\;(x-4)$$
 were canceled in the cross-multiplication step, but that was safe since, based on the original equation, none of those factors had the potential to be zero.

Comment: Yes, it's continuing from OP's question of what went wrong. Besides the OP's sign error, the key message here is that the choice of approach was not the best.

Comment: What went wrong is the choice of approach -- it was a recipe for disaster!

Comment: No, I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: Anyone can make a sign error. Identifying where a sign error occurred does not teach the OP much. Showing a simpler, more standard way provides a better learning experience.

Comment: @quasi: Your answer comes across very oddly. It would read much better if, instead of starting "But as I suggested in my comment..." it started something like "The approach you're taking is bound to cause problems..."

Comment: It's a style choice. I like the form of my answer, so I'll stay with it.

Comment: @quasi Is the implication of "cancelling algebraic terms that might actually be equal to zero" that we get a non-answer as in Mark Bennet's example? 

Also, how did you conclude that the factors $(x-1),\;(x-2),\;(x-3),\;(x-4)$ did not have the potential to be zero in the original equation?

Comment: @eriksan: They are denominators of the original equation.

Answer (score 8):

The error is in the third group of parentheses in the "multiplying factors again" step. What you have as $-12x$ should be positive.

Comment: Also, it is easy to see that $2.5$ must be a solution by exploiting the symmetry of the problem: we obviously get a solution if $x-1=4-x$ and $x-2=3-x$, which both say that $2x=5$.

Comment: I see how $x−1=4−x$ and $x−2=3−x$ are $2x=5$, but how did you come up with $x−1=4−x$ and $x−2=3−x$? I don't seem to understand the symmetry of the problem.

Comment: @eriksan: your equation has the form $a-b=c-d$. Certainly a sufficient condition for this to hold is to have $a=-d$ and $b=-c$. (It would also be sufficient to have $a=c$ and $b=d$, but you can see that in your problem that is not possible.) Of course, these are not the only two possibilities, so all my comment gives is a simple argument to find that $2.5$ is a solution; you would need another argument to conclude it is the *only* solution.

Comment: @eriksan: please accept an answer to close the question.

Answer (score 5):

A hint to make your life much simpler.

Always simplify your variables to start with. Here you can easily make the substitution $x-4 = y$ to get an easier equation in $y$.

Then noting that $\frac 1y - \frac 1{y+1} = \frac 1{y(y+1)}$, your can very easily see that the numerators on both sides when combining the rational expressions is just $1$ (to avoid confusion, note that I transposed the terms on each side to get a positive numerator). Taking the reciprocal on both sides and expanding, you get quadratics on both sides where the square terms immediately cancel, giving you a simple linear equation. Solve for $y$, then add $4$ to get $x$.

Comment: `the numerators on both sides when combining the rational expressions is just 1` That should rather be $\,-1\,$ since the two sides are of the form $\,\frac{1}{y+1}-\frac{1}{y}\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I transposed the terms on both sides first to keep both sides' numerators positive. Note the order of the terms in my answer.

Comment: I think that's worth spelling out in the answer. I didn't say it's outright wrong, but it may be confusing to the OP who appears to have already missed some clues in the problem itself.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, you're quite right. I've done so. I tend to do these mentally so I neglect to mention every step. It's my failing.

Comment: If I substitute $x-4 = y$ in $\frac{1}{(x-1)} - \frac{1}{(x-2)} = \frac{1}{(x-3)} - \frac{1}{(x-4)}$ I get $\frac{1}{(x-1)} - \frac{1}{(x-2)} = \frac{1}{(x-3)} - \frac{1}{y}$. How do you get to $\frac 1y - \frac 1{y+1} = \frac 1{y(y+1)}$?

Comment: @eriksan $x-4 =y \implies x=y+4$. Now replace *every* $x$ with $y+4$.

Comment: Ingenious. It was a while since I did variable substitution, I got it now!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way, which also illustrates how easy it is to make a mistake with these kinds of problems. If we take the negative fractions to the other side of the equation we get $$\frac 1{x-1}+\frac 1{x-4}=\frac 1 {x-3}+\frac 1{x-2}$$ which becomes $$\frac {2x-5}{(x-1)(x-4)}=\frac {2x-5}{(x-2)(x-3)}$$Now cancel and clear fractions to get $$(x-2)(x-3)=(x-1)(x-4)$$ or $$6=4$$

What went wrong? - Well in cancelling $2x-5$ I didn't check to make sure I was not dividing by zero - so the answer I want is $2x-5=0$ or $x=\frac 52$

Comment: if you calculate (x−2)(x−3)=(x−1)(x−4) you will find that 6 = 4 instead of 6 = 5

Comment: @rvheddeg Thanks!

Comment: @MarkBennet Checking the canceling factor $2x-5 = 0$... while running out of $x$ in the main calculation... I've never before seen arriving at an answer this way, unusual. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic error is already pinpointed. The result is a special case of the Theorem below

since we have $\ \overbrace{x\!-\!1\, +\, x\!-\!4}^{\Large a\ \ +\ \ b}  \, =\, \overbrace{x\!-\!2\, +\, x\!-\!3}^{\Large c\ \ +\ \ d}\ =\ \overbrace{\color{#c00}{2x\!-\!5}}^{\LARGE\color{#c00}s}\ \ $ and $\ \ \color{#0a0}{\overbrace{{x\!-\!2\neq x\!-\!1,\,x\!-\!4}}^{\Large c\ \neq\ a,\,b\quad\ \ }}\,$

therefore  $\quad\ \ \  \dfrac{1}{x\!-\!1}+\dfrac{1}{x\!-\!4} = \dfrac{1}{x\!-\!2}+\dfrac{1}{x\!-\!3}\!\iff\! \color{#c00}{2x\!-\!5} = 0$

**Theorem** $\ \ $ If  $\ a\!+\!b = c\!+\!d =: \color{#c00}s\ $ then $\ \dfrac{1}a+\dfrac{1}b =\dfrac{1}c+\dfrac{1}d \iff \color{#c00}{s = 0}\,$ or $\,\color{#0a0}{c = a}\,$ or $\,\color{#0a0}{c=b}$

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\qquad \dfrac{1}a+\dfrac{1}b\, &=\,\dfrac{1}c+\dfrac{1}d\\[.3em]
\iff \dfrac{s}{ab}&=\dfrac{s}{cd}\quad{\rm by} \ \ \ \color{#c00}s = a+b = c+d\\[.3em]
\iff\, \ \ 0\, &=\, s(ab-cd)\\[.3em]
&=\, s(ab-c(a+b-c))\\[.3em]
&=\, \color{#c00}s\color{#0a0}{(a-c)(b-c)}\\
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

To avoid errors or pitfalls it can sometimes be helpful to try an initial 'lazy  approach', where you still don't drop mathematical circumspection.

When looking at the equation a third degree polynomial can be sought, but that is no fun and we are really hoping that a quadratic equation 'pops-up'. The equation is ugly but perhaps by inverting the LHS and RHS things will simplify. We check that there is no $x$ with both the LHS and RHS equal to $0$ (see next section), so we can safely invert.

For the LHS,

$\frac {1} { \frac {1}{x-1} - \frac {1}{x-2}} = \frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{x-2-(x-1)} = -(x^2-3x+2)$

For the RHS,

$\frac {1} { \frac {1}{x-3} - \frac {1}{x-4}} = \frac{(x-3)(x-4)}{x-4-(x-3)} = -(x^2-7x+12)$

Combining our work,

$\tag 1 x^2 -3x +2 = x^2 -7x +12$

OMG! It is turning into a linear equation!

$\tag 2 4x = 10$

So $x = 2.5$

---

Examining

$\tag 3 \frac{1}{(x-1)} - \frac{1}{(x-2)} = \frac{1}{(x-3)} - \frac{1}{(x-4)}$

the LHS, $\frac{1}{(x-1)} - \frac{1}{(x-2)}$ is zero if and only if $x -
 1 = x - 2$, which is silly. So we can forget about looking for any $x$ solutions   that would make the LHS and RHS of (3) both equal to 0.

Comment: Cool way to reach the solution. Would have never thought about starting with inversion. How do you "check that there is no x with both the LHS and RHS equal to  0" systematically?

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut way to evaluate $$p(x):=(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) - (x-1)(x-3)(x-4)\\ - (x-2)(x-1)(x-4) + (x-1)(x-2)(x-3).$$

It is clear that this is a polynomial of at most second degree, as all cubic term will cancel out*.

Then we perform the easy evaluations

$$p(1)=-6,\ p(2)=-2,\ p(3)=2,\ p(4)=6$$ and clearly $$p(x)=4x-10.$$

---

*Actually we can also find the quadratic coefficient to be $$-2-3-4+1+3+4+2+1+4-1-2-3=0,$$ but we needn't use this fact, direct evaluation is anyway required to get the linear terms.

Comment: Cool, but that's a ninja move I don't understand, could you elaborate on a basic level how it relates to my problem?